# IServiceCollection.AddFacebookAuthentication - no definition and no method found trying to add facebook authentication in asp.net core

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0

I'm on a asp.net core 1.1 project, adding Facebook authentication. For reference, I didn't start the project as a "use identity", and instead started an empty project and moved over those items until I had a clean build (views, models, startup.cs changes, etc).

I added the Nuget package:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook
```

I followed the MSDN instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/facebook-logins

I got down to adding this, adding it to my Startup.cs in my ConfigureServices method, **I get an error on .AddFacebookAuthentication**:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;

//other code and sutff

services.AddFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions =>
{
    facebookOptions.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
    facebookOptions.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
});
```

The error I'm seeing:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1061  **'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for
>   'AddFacebookAuthentication' and no extension method
>   'AddFacebookAuthentication'** accepting a first argument of type
>   'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?)

Comment: are you sure the right version of that package was added by nuget, not the 2.0 preview version? Check under the dependencies > NuGet node in your project and verify the dependency is there and is for 1.x

Comment: @JoeAudette project->dependencies->Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook->Version=1.1.2   ... :(

Comment: the doc you link to is for 2.0, see my answer below for how to do it in 1.x

Answer (score 1):

I believe in 1.x you don't add that with services but instead in configure method like this:

```
app.UseFacebookAuthentication(facebookOptions =>
{
    facebookOptions.AppId = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
    facebookOptions.AppSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];

});
```

but in 2.0 it will be done with services and not like this

Answer (score 0):

## Facebook external login setup in ASP.NET Core

- Install Nuget Package

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook

- Startup.cs

> services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook(option => {
> option.AppId = "xxx-xxx-xxx";
> option.AppSecret = "xxx-xxx-xxx";
> });